# ShaderWallpaper Crashes My Desktop

Tags: kubuntu, crash, desktop-background

So, I have this refurbished desktop that I installed Kubuntu on. I was playing/tampering with the settings when I found the wallpaper plugins button. I clicked it and installed ShaderWallpaper. I was looking at the default shaders and noticed my CPU meter was at the max. I clicked some other ones, and my PC completely froze. The screen turned black except for my cursor. I figured out that ALT-SPACE works, so I used KFinder to launch Chrome, which is what I'm using to write this. Is there any fix for this dumb problem?

Comment: Generally, if you know how you caused a problem, the solution is to revert the change that is responsible.  In this case, go and change everything back that you were "playing/tampering with"

Comment: I actually ended up resetting my PC. I had just installed Kubuntu so it wasn't that big a deal. The thing was, I didn't know how to revert it. You can find the solution (I think) at the ShaderWallpaper Github page, on an error post.